# Flutter Is it possible to fade in and fade out markers for google_maps_flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-flutter

I think it would look nice if the markers faded in and out as they were presented. Is this possible with google_maps_flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, good news and bad news.

**The good news** is that it looks like markers have been made into widgets according to this entry in the google_maps_flutter pull requests here: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1240
which would (probably) mean that they can be manipulated by other flutter features.

**The bad news** is that I was unable to find any documentation on this feature (which isn't too surprising, given that this pull request was committed on March 6th, so it's fresh off the presses.) I posted a question to the writer of that pull request, user iskakaushik and asked if those widgets will be open to AnimatedOpacity, which would do exactly what you want.

So, I would check that thread and see how he responds.  It looks like you're going to be one of the first users of that feature!

Comment: Thank you for that. I hope it becomes possible soon!

Comment: I do too.  if I get a response, I'll post it here.

Comment: Any news on fading in out google maps markers I would be happy to upvote an answer ? : )